# SQL Server behavior when number scale is exceeded - how to change it?

Tags: sql-server

On SQL server, when I try to save value **0.4569** to a **decimal(9,3)** column, the value is truncated. It becomes **0.456**. It there a way how to change this behavior of sql server? I would like such numbers to be rounded (to **0.457** in my example) instead of truncating them.

Is there some global setting for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the definition of the column.

`DECIMAL (9,3)` means 9 digits, out of which 3 are for decimals.

In order to store your number, without changing the column definition, you will have to round to 3 digits in order to avoid truncation, so `ROUND(0.4596, 3)`.

Answer (score 0):

you can use also [ROUND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175003.aspx)

```
SELECT ROUND(0.4569,3) AS Col
```

OUTPUT

```
Col
0.4570
```